# Create a variable table and retrieve @COLUMN_NAME

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to retrieve @COLUMN_NAME of a table as a variable.
I use SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

```
declare @tmp TABLE ([TABLE_CATALOG] varchar(128), [TABLE_SCHEMA] varchar(128), [TABLE_NAME] varchar(128), [COLUMN_NAME] varchar(128), [ORDINAL_POSITION] varchar(128),[COLUMN_DEFAULT] varchar(128), 
 [IS_NULLABLE] varchar(128), [DATA_TYPE] varchar(128), [CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] varchar(128), [CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH] varchar(128), [NUMERIC_PRECISION] varchar(128), [NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX] varchar(128), [NUMERIC_SCALE] varchar(128), 
 [DATETIME_PRECISION] varchar(128), [CARACTER_SET_CATALOG] varchar(128), [CARACTER_SET_SCHEMA] varchar(128), [CARACTER_SET_NAME] varchar(128), [COLLATION_CATALOG] varchar(128), 
 [COLLATION_SCHEMA] varchar(128), [COLLATION_NAME] varchar(128), [DOMAIN_CATALOG] varchar(128), [DOMAIN_SCHEMA] varchar(128), [DOMAIN_NAME] varchar(128) )



INSERT INTO  @tmp 
EXEC sp_executesql (' SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'maTable' ')

DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME varchar(128)
SET @COLUMN_NAME =(SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM @tmp )
```

Here is the error that I get ==>

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near 'maTable'.

Even if I tried the same syntax before in an other code.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you

Comment: You can't have a single `'` inside a string. Double those as `... WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''maTable'' '`.

Comment: Could you update the question to explain what you expect the `@COLUMN_NAME` variable to contain? The (apparently unnecessary) dynamic SQL will return multiple column names, one for each column in `maTable`. `@COLUMN_NAME` can only hold one of these values. What do you want to do with `@COLUMN_NAME` once you have it?

Comment: In fact, I want to export SQL table into CSV using python. So I create a connection to the server via pyodbc and I should inject sql query inside my script ("Select top 5 * from maTable") and copy rows in a csv file. But the problem is that I can't keep Header of the table, I get just values. That's why I thought that I should correct my querry by taking in consideration ColumnName.

Comment: it doesn't work.  I correct my script and I got this error below. My query returns names of column which can't be stored in my variable '@COLUMN_NAME'  (Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
)

Comment: @Chym123 Time to start thinking about your code. Why do you think that error occurs? Your variable can hold a single value. That error indicates your table variable contains multiple rows. That is why you receive the error. That can be fixed - but you have already chosen the wrong path. No one knows what you are trying to do but what you have done won't work.

Comment: alright, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write

```
EXEC sp_executesql (' SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'maTable' ')`
```

you can write

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'maTable'
```